# How to move between tabs using trackpad on Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, touchpad

Using the new Safari I can move between tabs by swiping left and right with two fingers. When I try to do the same using Chrome it takes me back and forward on the same page I'm at.

How can I change the gesture for Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome OS, you can scroll through tabs by swiping left or right with three fingers. This may also work on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de). It allows you to have much more granular control over gestures than the standard OS X trackpad preferences, and you can do things like set per-application configurations for gestures. Even if there's no back/forward action for Chrome specifically, you should be able to set the gestures to activate the Back/Forward menu items or shortcuts.